# HTML 5 и JavaScript загрузчики файлов

Tags: javascript, html5

Подскажите html5 и javascript загрузчики изобр. файлов. Более интересует первое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Картинки](http://www.hotscripts.com/blog/javascript-image-cropping-scripts/)
- [Файлы](http://www.webmasters.by/articles/html-coding/176-multiupload-input-html5.html)